# Rails find value inside enumerator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Ok, so I've got this object @categories which is basically:

```
@categories = Category.all
```

passed into a page by a controller. So from here I want to grab the category field of the record with ID 12 (which is culled from another variable called currentCatId). So I do this:

```
currentCatId = 12
currentCat = @categories.find(currentCatId)
```

Wrong, this gives me all of the categories! Which I can't understand. So looking around I found that I could try something like this:

```
currentCat = @categories.find { |cat| cat.id = currentCatId }.category
```

This at least retrieves the field that I want, but not for the category with ID 12, but rather for the first category.

I'm going crazy here, can't understand why the instanced object has a .find method (that doesn't seem to work) but not a .where method.

What am I doing wrong and what's the correct way to do this?

Comment: you wanted a ==, but anyway, what's wrong about the O(1) `currentCat = Category.find(currentCatId)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As *meagar* says you should use `==` to compare. But anyway, what's wrong with the simple O(1) find:

```
@current_category = Category.find(current_category_id)
```

Comment: I saw that and tried it (since PHP is ==) but I get the same result, the first one, not the one with id 12. In my infinite ignorance, I didn't know you could call the Category model from that page, I thought you had to work only with whatever the controller passed to it, but this seems to do the trick, thanks so much, I was going crazy! You can tell I'm new to Rails...

Comment: So, if I understand this correctly, there's no sense in ever passing something like @categories = Category.all from a controller, simply call it from the form page (or whatever page you're at)? Except if you need to find all the entries in a table since Category.each doesn't exist.

Comment: no, no, the right place to do a find like this is the controller, just put a `@current_category = Category.find(current_category_id)` in your action.

Comment: @kukbei ***NO***. The entire point of an MVC separation, is to load your models from your database *in the controller*. Doing this in the view itself is completely wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Your example using `find { ... }` is nearly correct, but you have a bug: You're using `=` to test equality when you need to use `==`. A single equal sign is *always* assignment.

```
currentCat = @categories.find { |cat| cat.id == currentCatId }.category
```

Comment: I saw that and tried it (since PHP is ==) but I get the same result, the first one, not the one with id 12.

Comment: @kakubei: you say it does not work with ==, but why you add another ".category" at the end. It's already a category, it may the parent category or who knows.

Answer (score 1):

Category.all is an Array, not an ActiveRecord::Relation.

You can try this on the Rails console:

```
# Returns an Array
Category.all.class 

# Returns an ActiveRecord::Relation
Category.where(:id => 1)
```

ActiveRecord::Relation is the class that gives you .where.
Array, like ActiveRecord::Base, has .find, which is probably why you got confused.

Comment: I understand that distinction, but don't know how to then get the record with that ID from an ActiveRecord::Relation